# Two types of products using ubercart..?

Tags: drupal, vb6, ubercart

I am working on a website which sells books and journals. My problem is the books will be sold our directly where as in the case of journals case the journals, they can be subscribed for the whole year / per issue or per chapter also.

Can i have both of them as products using ubercart in the same site?

Thanks & Regards,
Satya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the core Ubercart functionality. Just go to Store Administration > Products > Manage Classes. Then you can add as many types of product as you like. After you've added a new class here, you'll get a new content type that you can add custom fields to and maintain just like any other CCK type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UC Recurring Payments and Subscriptions module](http://drupal.org/project/uc_recurring) to add the ability to subscribe to the journals. That module won't interfere with the ability to add other types of products available for purchase.